# TextBox is not getting value in Grid View

Tags: c#, .net

MasterDataEntry.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows)
    {

        string str1 = ((TextBox)oItem.FindControl("Country")).Text;
        string str2 = ((DropDownList)oItem.FindControl("Status")).SelectedValue;
        string str3 = ((TextBox)oItem.FindControl("TxtBox1")).Text;

        insertData(str1, str2, str3);
    }   

    void insertData (string str1, string str2, string str3)
    {
        //con.Open();
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=EXT-SQLSTG-1;Initial Catalog=DataEntry;Integrated Security=True");

        // SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
         //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //cmd.CommandType = "insert into Mastertables (GovEntitiesId,PriortiesId,OutcomesId,CountryId,StatusId,Justification,) values('" + dbGovEntities + "','" + dbPriorties + "','" + dbOutComes + "','" + str1 +"','" + str2 + "','" + str3+ "')";
        string sql = "insert into Mastertables (GovEntitiesId,PriortiesId,OutcomesId,CountryId,StatusId,Justification) values('" + dbGovEntities.SelectedValue + "','" + dbPriorties.SelectedValue + "','" + dbOutComes.SelectedValue + "',(Select id from Countries where CountryName='"+str1+"'),'" + str2 + "','" + str3 + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
    }
}
```

MasterDataEntry.aspx

The TxtAra ,textbox is not getting values.
SO inserting the data from grid view in a loop
 but the problem is the str3 string doesn't have anything
or it is not getting from textbox TXTAra

Comment: The only mention of `TxtAra` is in your question body, not the code

Comment: string str3 = ((TextBox)oItem.FindControl("TxtBox1")).Text;Sorry the above str3 line is wrong.this is the right one!

Comment: string str3 = ((TextBox)oItem.FindControl("TxtAra")).Text;
you mean TxTAra and not TextBox1 right?

Answer (score 0):

If your control is having ID as "TXTAra", you are finding it wrongly by name "TxtBox1". Please correct it to -

string str3 = ((TextBox)oItem.FindControl("TxtAra")).Text;

Also confirm if the textbox is a direct child of gridviewrow.

Answer (score 0):

I just add EnableViewState=False and it worked.Pasting the code below.

Thanks for support.